If $f$ is zero at a neighborhood of a point $t_0$ then $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R \hat{f}(w)e^{iwt_0} dw = 0$
We take $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that that there exists $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $f(t) =0$ for every $t \in B_\delta(t_0)$ and $\hat{f}$ denotes the fourier transform of $f$.
I'm a bit stuck on this problem because we can't use inversion or anything like that because we don't have that $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. I know this is a result that is also valid for fourier series (the riemann localization theorem) but in this case we are trying to prove the same thing for fourier integrals. I've also been searching for criteria on pointwise convergence of the fourier integrals but most of what I can found is about series, which doesn't help me here.
I've tried to use that we must have points of differentiability on $B_\delta(t_0)$ but I don't know how to proceed here. Any help is appreciated.

This is a result which you can obtain from using the Riemann-Lebesgue-Lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma). We just write the fourier Transform $\widehat f(w)$ as an integral and use Fubini's theorem and some standard calculations:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-R}^R \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{-ixw} dx e^{iwt_0} dw &= \int_\mathbb{R} \int_{-R}^R f(x) e^{iw(t_0-x)} dw dx\\\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{f(x)}{i(t_0-x)} \left [e^{iR(t_0-x)} - e^{-iR(t_0-x)} \right ] dx\\\\
&=2 \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{f(x)}{t_0-x} \sin(R(t_0-x)) dx\\\\
&= -2 \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f(t_0-y)}{y} \sin(Ry) dy.
\end{align*}
Now the function $y \mapsto \frac{f(t_0-y)}{y}$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ because of $f(t_0-y)=0$ for $|y|<\delta$. Hence $\left \lvert \frac{f(t_0-y)}{y}\right \rvert \le \frac{1}{\delta} |f(t_0-y)|$ which shows that the function is $L^1$.
Now the Riemann-Lebesgue-Lemma implies (in the complex version of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma the integral we have right now is basically the imaginary part)
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{f(t_0-y)}{y} \sin(Ry) dy =0$$
which is exactly the claim.

(+1) for the concise and well-written post
